# In PHP are recalls to any given function the variable they return or a call to the function itself

Tags: php

For example:

```
<?php
    $text="/p hello";
    $a= explode("/",$text);
    $a=$a[1];
    echo $a;
?>
```

works, however:

```
<?php
    $text="/p hello";
    $a= explode("/",$text)[1];
    echo $a;
?>
```

results in a syntax error. In python you can just treat a recall to a function that returns a list/array as a list/array. Is this the same for php?

Comment: Why won't you check at yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP version >= 5.4.0 it will not result in error, but will echo `p_hello`. You can check it here, changing the version number:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/db319c296ea4eb9500b9fa16bccd8f927c733d14

It is called Function Array Dereferencing:

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing

Comment: Thanks it seems I was using an outdated version of php (5.3). :)